# How to use spatie/laravel-multitenancy with single database?

Tags: php, laravel, database

I'm trying to implement multi tenancy in my Laravel project using the spatie/laravel-multitenancy package. I want to use a single database with a tenant_id column in each tenant-specific table. However, I'm getting this error when I run `php artisan migrate --tenant`:

"C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel-saas\public\index.php56[top]"

Here is the code I have in my config/tenancy.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Stancl\Tenancy\Database\Models\Tenant as BaseTenant;

use Stancl\Tenancy\Contracts\TenantWithDatabase;

use Stancl\Tenancy\Database\Concerns\HasDatabase; use Stancl\Tenancy\Database\Concerns\HasDomains;

class Tenant extends BaseTenant implements TenantWithDatabase

{

use HasDatabase, HasDomains;}
```

I expect the migration to run successfully and create the tenant-specific tables in the same database as the landlord tables. I followed the instructions from the package documentation and this tutorial, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Does anyone know how to fix this error or what I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add more information like php version laravel version or something else. In my case, it's possible with multi database, maybe

Comment: I can't see what the actual error is. All I see is a path to the index.php file